# Slide Menu Library error

Tags: android

I used [Slide menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library into my android project and when I include this the eclipse fire and error at project.R.id cause it can't access my project.R

Comment: a snap shot of how you refer the library project in your project would help

Answer (score 1):

`android.R.id` is different from `R.id`, do not import `android.R` as this will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `import android.R` and make sure you have marked the slideMenu project as "Is Library" by going in its property->Java build path option. After it clean your main project once.